# RPGLE - How to Convert String to ProperCase / TitleCase

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

In the RPGLE programming Langause on the IBMi/iseries/AS400 how does one go about converting a character string to ProperCase / TitleCase?

As per usual, I have google my $%# off and ended up Frankensteining my own solution.

This is documented below, as I will in inevitably need to use this proc again. At least I know that google will find a solution for me.

**@FutureSelf** => Whoomp THERE IT IS!!!

Comment: Somebody done that with java?

Comment: @danny117 Try Googling for Split/Explode Strings

Comment: @Past Self => Thanks. You Legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ?*--------------------------------------------------
 ?* Procedure name: ConverToTitleCase
 ?*--------------------------------------------------
   dcl-proc ConvertToTitleCase export;
     dcl-pi *n  varchar();
       i_String varchar() const;
     end-pi;

     dcl-s o_String varchar();
     dcl-s w_Text char();
     dcl-s w_Word char();
     dcl-s p_Word pointer;
     dcl-s p_Last pointer;

     dcl-c UPPER const(0);
     dcl-c lower const(1);

     dcl-pr GetToken pointer ExtProc('strtok_r');
       String pointer value options(*string);
       Seps   pointer value options(*string);
       Lasts  pointer ;
     end-pr;
     dcl-c BLANK const(' ');
     //-------------------------------------------------
     if %trim(i_String) = *blanks;
       return i_String; //Nothing to Convert;
     endif;
     //-------------------------------------------------
     p_Word = GetToken(ConvertCase(i_String:lower):BLANK:p_Last);
     dow p_Word <> *null;

       w_Word = %str(p_Word);
       %subst(w_Word:1:1) = ConvertCase(%subst(w_Word:1:1):UPPER);
       o_String += BLANK + w_Word;
       p_Word = GetToken(*NULL:BLANK:p_Last);
     enddo;
     //-------------------------------------------------
     return o_String;
   end-proc;
   //***************************************************
   dcl-proc ConvertCase;
     dcl-pi *n  varchar();
       i_String varchar() const;
       i_CaseTo int(5)    const;
     end-pi;

     dcl-s o_String varchar();

     //Control Block for the call to QglConvertCase.
     dcl-ds FormatOfRequestControlBlock;
       ReqType  int(10)  inz(1); //Convert String
       CCSID    int(10)  inz(0); //CCSID of JOB
       CaseTo   int(10)  inz(0); //Default Lower
       Reserved char(10) inz(*ALLX'00');
     end-ds;

     dcl-s APIError char(16) inz(*ALLX'00');

     dcl-pr QlgCvtCase ExtProc('QlgConvertCase');
       ctrlBlock  LikeDS(FormatOfRequestControlBlock) Const;
       inString   char(65535)   Options(*VARSIZE)     Const;
       OutString  char(65535)   Options(*VARSIZE);
       Length     int(10) Const;
       APIError   like(APIError);
     end-pr;

     if %len(%trim(i_String)) <= 0;
       return i_String; //Noting to convert;
     endif;

     FormatOfRequestControlBlock.CaseTo = i_CaseTo;

     QlgCvtCase(FormatOfRequestControlBlock
               :i_String
               :o_String
               :%len(i_String)
               :APIError);

     return %Subst(o_String:1:%Len(i_String));
   end-proc;
   //***************************************************
```

Comment: Nice work, I expected to see it limited to CCSID 37 by the use of 'ABC...' 'abc...'.